# accessing separate classes in a dll C#

Tags: c#, dll

im trying to access a few classes i have in a dll. below is my dll (utils) and the classes that im trying to access inside of it (delim). but the only thing that i can access and use in the utils dll is kb.cs. i have no access to mouse.cs or delim.cs. which are the two that im in need of using.
[image]
here is how im trying to access it. i have it in references, as you can see on the right hand side of the image. and i also have "using utils;" in there
[image]

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delim` must be declared `public` for the class to be visable in other assemblies (dll's and exe's)

```
public class delim
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: ... thanks, im new to classes. so its these little thing that get me.

Answer (score 1):

Classes are `internal` by default.It means that you can't access it from outside of the assembly of your class.You need to make your class `public`.